# Dreamweaver JQuery scrollorama

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dreamweaver

i cant get scrollorama to work in dreamweaver i will admit that im new to jquery but ive been scrubbing for the answer for a few days now and cant seem to get anything to function correctly or the function to work at all

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="Untitled-5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.scrollorama.js"></script>
<script src="js/playjs.js">

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="scrollblock" id="intro1">

  <h1 id="title1">Block 1</h1>

</div>



<div class="scrollblock" id="intro2">

  <h1 id="title2">Block 2</h1>

</div>

<div class="scrollblock" id="intro3">

  <h1 id="title3">Block 3</h1>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

then the js

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    var scrollorama = $.scrollorama({ blocks:'.scrollblock' });
scrollorama.animate('#title1',{ duration: 300, property:'zoom', end: 8 });
scrollorama.animate('#title2',{ duration: 600, property:'rotate', start:90,end:270 });
scrollorama.animate('#title3',{ duration: 600, property:'left', start:-800,end: 0 });
});
```

I'm using this tutorial markup to figure out what I'm doing wrong but I can't seem to figure it out...this isn't even working...I don't know if it's an issue trying to run the plugin through dreamweaver or some syntax issue considering the fact that I'm new to this

Comment: What do you mean _"in dreamweaver"_?

Comment: should've been more specific...when i was trying to preview the page locally...i don't expect the plugin to work in the dreamweaver app

Comment: Preview locally? In a browser? Which one? Are you running a web server? In any case, Scrollorama is just a demo. Use [SuperScrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/) for real development.